# Why am I getting an "inaccessible due to protection level" error?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, access-modifiers

I am getting this error:

> 'CTest.A.A()' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

when compiling this code:

```
public class A
{
    private A()
    {
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the default constructor for A is private, try `protected A() {}` as the constructor.

Class `B` automatically calls the default constructor of `A`, if that is inaccessible to `B` or there is no default constructor (if you have constructor `protected A(string s) {}`) `B` can not be instantiated correctly.

The compiler automatically generates the following default constructor in `B`

```
public B() : base()
{
}
```

Where `base()` is the actual call to the default constructor of `A`.

Comment: Not quite the whole story though. Even if B is an abstract class you will get the same compile error. An abstract class has no constructor, but the compiler still enforces the rule, since a class C derived from B would have the same issue. (Note that this is the case even if there is no class derived from C.)

Answer (score 3):

The constructor on class `B` (which is added by the compiler) needs to call the default (no-args) constructor on `A`, however the default constructor is marked as `private`, which means it can only be called inside `A`, hence the error.

Change the constructor on `A` to `protected` or `public`, or `internal` if `B` is in the same assembly.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor for A is private, it cannot be accessed from outside. If you want to create an instance of A from outside, make the constructor public or protected.

Answer (score 1):

Change `private A()` to `public A()` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It's because A's constructor is private, but B's constructor is public. When you construct B (which constructs A as well) there is no way to access A's private constructor.

Comment: What does B's constructor being public have to do with anything?

Comment: how would you instantiate B with private constructor? I just pointed out that B can be instantiated

Comment: You can use a static factory method on B that calls the private constructor of B (that needs to call a public or protected constructor of A)

Comment: Who says anything about instantiation? The compiler error has nothing to do with B's ctor being public